# Google Maps Info window by url parameters only

Tags: url, google-maps

How can we display the info window of google map by just using the url parameter.
like.
http://maps.google.com/?qCalifornia, United States&infowindow="address"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

Here's the way to add info windows: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows